# Update element of LinkedHashSet which is a collection

Tags: java

I have a nested collection structure representing Schema, Table, Column

```
public class SSchema{
    private String schemaName;
    private LinkedHashSet<STable> tableSet;
}
public class STable {
    private String tableFullName;
    private String tableDisplayName;
    private LinkedHashSet<SColumn> columnSet;
}
public class SColumn {
    private String columnFullName;
    private String columnDisplayName;
    private String columnType;
}
```

I retrieve the list of columns from an API and populate a LinkedHashSet of columns, I then get the Tables these columns belong to and am trying to update the LinkedHashSet of Columns inside each Table. Unfortunately, there is no API to get the columns for a table in this API

```
LinkedHashSet<SColumn> sColumnSet = getSColumnsFromAPI();
LinkedHashSet<STable> sTableSet = getSTablesForColumns(sColumnSet);
```

In the function getSTablesForColumns,

```
private LinkedHashSet<STable> getSTablesForColumns(LinkedHashSet<SColumn> sColumnSet) throws IOException,JsonParseException {
        sTableSet = new LinkedHashSet<STable>();
        sColumnSet.forEach(sColumn -> {
        String[] tablesList = getTablesFromApi(sColumn) //get the tables this column is in
        foreach(String tableName:tablesList){
           STable table = STable.builder()
                                  .tableFullName(tableName)
                                  .build();
           //This is where the problem is - need a way to get the existing table
           if(sTableSet.contains(table){
                 // get existing table from sTableSet - how do I do this?
                 existingTable.getColumnSet().add(stiboColumn);
           }
           else { //new table, not in collection
               LinkedHashSet<SColumn> columnSet = new LinkedHashSet<SColumn>();
               columnSet.add(sColumn);
               table.setColumnSet(columnSet);
               sTableSet.add(table);
                 };
            }
      });
    return sTableSet;
}
```

The question/difficulty I am having is: How do I efficiently find the existing sTable in the LinkedHashSet and update the LinkedHashSet inside this sTable with the additional sColumn?

**Edit:**
I came up with the following fix before the much better solution below:

My earlier solution was to check if the table existed in the collection (I had moved the sTableSet to a class variable):

```
boolean existingTable=false;
   for(STable sTable : sTableSet){
      String collectionSTableName = sTable.getTableFullName();
      if (collectionSTableName.equals(table)){
            existingTable=true;
            sTable.getColumnSet().add(sColumn);
            break;
      }
   }
   if(existingTable==false) { //new table, not in collection
       LinkedHashSet<SColumn> columnSet = new LinkedHashSet<SColumn>();
       columnSet.add(sColumn);
       table.setColumnSet(columnSet);
       sTableSet.add(table);
   };
```

Comment: What are the `equals` and `hashCode` implementations for `STable`?  Modifying elements of a `Set` is a recipe for almost guaranteed disaster.  Instead, you should remove the preexisting element and add a new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line of `getSTablesForColumns` you are reinitializing the global field `sTableSet`. If you ever call this method again, you will be losing what was already stored.

However, aside from that you, the data structure you might be looking for is a `HashMap`. (I've also changed the return type to void to avoid that first problem)

```
Class Test {
   private Map<String, STable> sTableMap = new HashMap<>();

   public Test() {
      LinkedHashSet<SColumn> sColumnSet = getSColumnsFromAPI();
      updateSTablesForColumns(sColumnSet); // sTableMap will be populated after this call
   }

   private void updateSTablesForColumns(LinkedHashSet<SColumn> sColumnSet) throws IOException,JsonParseException {
        sColumnSet.forEach(sColumn -> {
           String[] tablesList = getTablesFromApi(sColumn) //get the tables this column is in
           for (String tableName : tablesList){
              STable table = STable.builder()
                                     .tableFullName(tableName)
                                     .build();
   
              STable existingTable = sTableMap.get(table.getTableFullName());
              if(existingTable != null){
                  existingTable.getColumnSet().add(stiboColumn);
              } else { //new table, not in collection
                  LinkedHashSet<SColumn> columnSet = new LinkedHashSet<SColumn>();
                  columnSet.add(sColumn);
                  table.setColumnSet(columnSet);
                  sTableMap.put(table.getTableFullName(), table);
              }
           }
      });
   }

}
```

Be aware about side effects and modifying your parameters inside functions. In your method here you are changing `sColumnSet` by calling `sColumnSet.add()`. Which means your paramter after the method call is now changed. Also you shouldn't add to a collection while iterating over it. You may even get an exception here  `columnSet.add(sColumn);`

Comment: Thank you, I will be accepting your answer because it is better than what I did to make the code work, which I'm posting below.